# How to shift and adding lists for overlap–add method convolution?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

This is the overlap-add method of block convolution. Assume that you already knew `y0`, `y1`, `y2`. How would you calculate the output `y` as in the table below or the expression for y that I wrote below?

```
y0 = {1, 3, 3, 4, \[Minus]1, 2};
y1 = {1, 4, 5, 3, 0, 2};
y2 = {1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0};
```

I think I can do it by using PadLeft and PathRight to add zeros to  each list and then sum them.

```
y = {1, 3, 3, 4, \[Minus]1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} + {0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 3, 
  0, 2, 0, 0, 0} + {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0}
```

However, this method is a bit long. I wonder if there is a shorter way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Could you please include any information about `n` and `h`?

Comment: Any reason why not implement the algorithm as described in the literature? [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) and [mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41338-block-convolution-using-overlap-add-method) for examples.

Comment: @Syed it's from page 144 of the book below.
https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/intro2sp/orfanidis-i2sp.pdf

Comment: @Nasser That is nice too. I was just reading the book and wonder how to add them using mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
y=ConstantArray[0,12];

y[[1;;6]]  += y0;
y[[4;;9]]  += y1;
y[[7;;12]] += y2;

y
(* {1,3,3,5,3,7,4,3,3,0,1,0} *)
```

Here is another:

```
Total[MapThread[ArrayPad,{
   {y0,y1,y2},
   {{0,6},{3,3},{6,0}}}]]

(* {1,3,3,5,3,7,4,3,3,0,1,0} *)
```

Comment: Nice, looks simple but I have never thought of.

Answer (score 3):

Using the idea of generating function.

```
expr = y0 . {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}*1 + 
   y1 . {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5} x^3 + 
   y2 . {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5} x^6;
CoefficientList[expr, x]
```

> `{1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 7, 4, 3, 3, 0, 1}`

Comment: You're really smart.